# Using String reader to manage multiple lines

Tags: c#, string

So this is my current code:

```
string serverInfo = "Connected to 74.91.119.188:27015\n" +
                            "hostname:[FN] 24 / 7 Surf Utopia | Styles | !KNIFE,!WS,!GLOVES\n" +
                            "version: 1.37.9.5 secure\n" +
                            "os      :  Linux\n" +
                            "type    :  community dedicated\n" +
                            "map: surf_utopia_v3\n" +
                            "players : 24 humans, 0 bots(64 / 0 max)(not hibernating)\n" +

                            "# userid name uniqueid connected ping loss state rate\n" +
                            "# 3785 1 \"Con\" STEAM_1:0:128083116 03:13 32 0 active 196608\n" +
                            "# 3786 2 \"yolo\" STEAM_1:0:172863146 03:13 171 0 active 196608\n" +
                            "# 3787 3 \"chodyツ\" STEAM_1:0:42129452 03:13 46 0 active 786432\n" +
                            "#end\n";
        var removeEnd = serverInfo.IndexOf("#end");
        var newString = serverInfo.Remove(removeEnd);
        var firstHashTag = newString.IndexOf("#");
        var secondHashTag = newString.IndexOf("#", firstHashTag + 1);
        var final = newString.Substring(secondHashTag);

        var newFinal = final.Replace("# ", "#");

        using (StringReader reader = new StringReader(newFinal.ToString()))
        {
            string readText = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();

            int foundS1 = readText.IndexOf(" ");
            int foundS2 = readText.IndexOf(" ", foundS1 + 1);

            newFinal2 = readText.Remove(foundS1 + 1, foundS2 - foundS1);

            Console.WriteLine(newFinal2);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
```

[Result from code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jbe7l.png)

My question is. How can I modify this portion:

```
            using (StringReader reader = new StringReader(newFinal.ToString()))
        {
            string readText = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();

            int foundS1 = readText.IndexOf(" ");
            int foundS2 = readText.IndexOf(" ", foundS1 + 1);

            newFinal2 = readText.Remove(foundS1 + 1, foundS2 - foundS1);

            Console.WriteLine(newFinal2);
        }
```

So that it applies to every line there might be? The string serverInfo is data I've typed myself, but usually I would get this data from the API. Each line represents a player, and I don't know how many there might be, when I eventually get the data from the API, so I need a solution that doesn't know how many lines there will be. So how can I remove something from every line, where the conditions are the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split the lines using the `string.Split` function:

```
var userLines = newFinal.Split(Environment.NewLine);
foreach (var userLine in userLines)
{
    Console.WriteLine(userLine);
}
```